# Books for data sources

Tags: references, dataset

There are many books on data science that describe in detail learning algorithms and methods. But another important step in data science is data collection and feature engineering. Are there books solely devoted to this topic?

The book should be a collection of several data sets, recommendations on how these datasets were obtained and then cleaned. Discussion of Feature engineering will be a bonus but not required. I am looking for seminal books that cover the process of collecting a wide variety of datasets for academic research purpose.

Comment: Collecting data is very domain specific. What exactly do you have in mind? Planning experiments, observational studies, agriculture studies, gathering meteorological data, using EEG, administering psychological questionnaires, planning surveys, doing simulation studies, scrapping web pages, using SQL, building data-collecting plugins for web pages, list of freely available datasets, etc.? As you see, this is pretty broad and diverse to fit into a single book. Cleaning data is also problem specific.

Comment: something along the lines of collecting healthcare data of civilians or other societal information on which AI can be applied for social good.

Comment: Please edit to clarify your post -- e.g. "socures" in the title and "engg" in the body.